# String format using MultiBinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding, string-formatting

I'm trying to display a string in XAML using Label control. Following is my XAML code :

```
<Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,68,0,0" Name="label13" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} x {1}">
              <Binding Path="Width" />
              <Binding Path="Height" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
```

Width and Height are two properties of my class Movie.
I want the label to display : "Width x Height" ex. 800 x 640
However the label control remains empty. Any help is appreciated.
I WANT TO DO THIS WITHOUT USING A CONVERTER.

---

I have modified my xaml by using a TextBlock instead of Label. But still it wont populate display the output.

```
<TextBlock Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,68,0,0" Name="label13" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} x {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Width" />
                        <Binding Path="Height" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010772/binding-stringformat

Comment: have you implement the INotificationChanged interface for your class movie? is your Binding correct? (look at the vs output window)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

you are trying to bind a string to an object. But StringFormat requires its target to be a string type.

try putting a TextBlock in your label content and bind your data to it

```
<StackPanel>
  <Slider x:Name="sl1" Minimum="10" Maximum="100"/>
  <Slider x:Name="sl2" Minimum="10" Maximum="100"/>
  <Label x:Name="label13" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Black">
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} x {1} Test">
              <Binding ElementName="sl1" Path="Value" />
              <Binding ElementName="sl2" Path="Value" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
  </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT**
your class Movie must implement the INotificationPropertyChanged interface and your two properties must raise the property changed event with their proprty names!

hope this helps

Comment: can you elaborate why it works when `TextBlock` is inside `Label` and doesn't work otherwise?

Comment: @IgorStack because the target of the binding is a different type.  `TextBlock.Text` is a `string`, but `Label.Content` is an `object`.  The `StringFormat` property only kicks in for string-typed targets.