# MultiBinding ComboBoxItem.Content

Tags: wpf

Hi I am trying to achieve a binding like this:

```
<ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle2}">
    <ComboBoxItem.Content>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Value" Source="{StaticResource Name}" />
            <Binding Path="Name" Source="{StaticResource Person}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBoxItem.Content>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Where "Name" is a localized string and "Value" is used to get it's localized string. 
for some reason this doesn't seems to work. I am getting empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the corrected code:

```
<ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle2}">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                <Binding Path="Value" Source="{StaticResource Name}" />
                <Binding Path="Name" Source="{StaticResource Person}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

I need to fix two things:

1. Keep the content as TextBlock and do binding of text there.
2. Removed extra spacing from StringFormat i.e. " {}{0} {1}" ==> "{}{0} {1}".

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: [String format using MultiBinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377471/string-format-using-multibinding)

Taken from that post:

You are trying to bind a string to an object. But StringFormat requires its target to be a string type. Try putting a TextBlock in your content and bind your data to it.

Also put "" around Name.

Answer (score 0):

You Can see this link i wish be helpful

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32b81578-b201-4927-bdc2-ebb9a42ae303/comboboxdisplaymemberpath-and-multibinding