# How to fix StringFormat in multiBinding with condition in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `MultiBinding` in `TextBlock` with a condition that allow one on two strings to be displayed,
and i want to add a string format to one of the two strings but i can't add it to a

please help!

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Title}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource 
            ConvertisseurMultipleConcatenator}"
            ConverterParameter=" ">
                <Binding Path="returnBoolean"
                     Converter="{StaticResource ConvertModification}" 
                                 ConverterParameter=" " />                        
                <Binding Path="Name" />
                <Binding Source=":"/>
       </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<convertisseur:ConvertisseurBooleenObject x:Key="ConvertModification"
                                            Faux="{x:Static 
   ressources:Ressources.AJOUT_ASSURANCE_LIBELLE_ASSURE}"
                                            Vrai="{x:Static 
   ressources:Ressources.AJOUT_ASSURANCE_DETAIL_ASSURE}"/>
```

want to replace IT with this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={x:Static 
           ressources:Ressources.SOME_RESSOURCE}}"
           Style="{StaticResource Text}">                               
</TextBlock>
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool returnBoolean{
        get {
            return Age() <= 12;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add your ConvertisseurMultipleConcatenator definition?

Comment: This question has some similarity to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377471/string-format-using-multibinding

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I have removed the ConvertisseurMultipleConcatenator to use TextBlock in a Grid,

Comment: my expected output is a string formated with a paramter if boolean is Flase, or a simple string without a stringFormat