# Binding String Format

Tags: xaml, binding, string-formatting

Is it possible to bind the StringFormat property in a binding?  My intuition tells me you can't put a binding in a binding, but what I'd like to do is:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myText, StringFormat={Binding myFormat}}"/>
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind StringFormat at all. StringFromat is not dependency property and therefore it is not bindable. If you want to achive this you have to do it in code behind or in case you use a MVVM pattern yu should do it in the view model. You can alo try this solution which uses MultiBinding. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010782/7808992).