# WPF XAML string interpolation

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm struggling to achieve string interpolation in `Setter` of the `TextBlock` in XAML.

I have a string with a `{0}` inside and want this "tag" to be replaced by some text. I'd use `Multibinding` and break my message into parts, but my app should be translated to other languages. For example, I have message like `"Das Verzeichnis {0} wurde nicht gefunden"` which due to semantics of different languages may look different, for example `"The following path could nont been found: {0}"`. Sure, in this case I still can paraphrase it and then break into 3 parts to give a proper `StringFormat` to the `Multibinding`, but there is no guarantee it will work, let's say in Japanese. I also can't use multiple `Run`s, since `Setter` only receives one value.

Is there a way to get something similar to `string.Format()` in XAML?

**UPD**: Code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static vm:StatesEnum.UnknownError}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding to resource string}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

**UPD2**: I wrote a simple converter, that makes all that stuff with string formatting. However, Binding seems to be tricky. XAML code below illustrates my problem. I need to bind to the whole DataContext of it, because `State` from the `DataTrigger` (first listing) is not sufficient for the text I want, I need some other fields from the bound object.

```
<Style x:Key="ImageErrorTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=???, Converter={StaticResource ImageToError}}" />
</Style>
```

However, as I found out, use of converter does not allow use of `{Binding}` (without `Path=some_field`). Leaving `Path` empty is allowed, but in this case `Convert` is only called once (probably creation or initialization of `DataContext`). The problem is, that the `DataContext` is declared in code behind and lies in collection, which is not bound to anything, so I have to apply this converter either in code behind or via setters in style. How can I bind `Converter` to the `{Binding}` or maybe there is another way of accessing the whole bound object?

Comment: I think you should use a multi value converter with multi binding for Text property on TextBlock. If your second part of message is empty just pass a string empty if you really want to. But without xaml and code of what you are doing it is difficult to advise you.

Comment: Well there is a string.Format() equivalent, but unfortunately you cannot bind it, so no good for localisation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010772/binding-stringformat

Comment: I hate it when someone deletes a question while I write an answer. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database model. The classes you use don't have to be exact copies of the tables. You can use different DbContexts for different use cases, with entities that fulfill the needs of the specific use case, containing only the needed fields

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this :)

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static vm:StatesEnum.UnknownError}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
                <Binding Path="" Converter=""/>
                <Binding Path="" Converter=""/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```