# TextBox Text IMultiValueConverter and additional binding parameters

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TextBox that looks something like this:-

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Scale, NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
               UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, StringFormat={}{0:g5}}" />
```

I'd like to use a multi value converter for the Text property, as I want to bind `StringFormat` rather than hardcode it in xaml (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010782/981831)). Am I right in saying that using such a converter leaves me with no way to specify further binding expression "parameters", such as `NotifyOn...` and `UpdateSourceTrigger` seen in my example? (I realise the UpdateSourceTrigger default *is* LostFocus, but there might be times where I'd want to use PropertyChanged, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right in saying that using such a converter leaves me with no way to specify further binding expression "parameters" ...?

No, MultiBinding does also have all these properties, and you specify them like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}"
                      NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                      NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding Path="Scale"/>
            <Binding Path="YourStringFormat"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```