# WPF GridView different stringformat for each item on gridviewcolumn binding

Tags: wpf, datagridview, binding, string-formatting

I'm trying to bind the StringFormat of a column binding depending on each datacontext item's individually.

Here's the sample code:

xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Symbols}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gw">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price, StringFormat={Binding StringFormat}}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<symbol> Symbols { get;set;}

public class symbol : INotifyPropertyChanged    
    {

        #region INotify Handler

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        #endregion


        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }


        private double _price;
        public double Price
        {
            get => _price;
            set
            {
                _price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
            }
        }


        private int _decimalplaces;
        public int decimalplaces
        {
            get => _decimalplaces;
            set
            {
                _decimalplaces = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(decimalplaces));
                if (value == 0)
                    StringFormat = "0";//no decimal 
                else
                    StringFormat = $"0.{new string('0', value)}";//like 0.000 for 3 decimal places
            }
        }

        public string StringFormat { get; set; }


    }
```

The `StringFormat={Binding StringFormat}` is not possible, I've just put it there to demonstrate what I exactly wanted. Each item's (symbol) format is different.

It doesn't matter if I need to add the columns in code behind, I can do it but I just don't know how to.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: One option would be to use a multibinding like was done [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010782/493566).

Answer (score 0):

Update:
There is a solution I didn't want to use but now I believe it's the only logical way.

```
private double _price;
public double Price
{
    get => _price;
    set
    {
        _price = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
        StringPrice = value.ToString(format);
    }
}
private string _stringprice;
public string StringPrice
{
    get => _stringprice;
    set {
        _stringprice = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringPrice));
    }
}
```

and using it in XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StringPrice}" />
```

Comment: Isn't that grid view read only? StringPrice could just have a lambda getter which formats Price. And Price raise property changes for StringPrice if necessary.